# MS Office Word - EXCEL

Tags: windows, email, microsoft-office, microsoft-excel-2007, merge

I've got a problem:

- I want to create one document, consisting of different documents.
- Using an excel sheet (comparable to mail merge therefore)

! But: Every recipient has a different content. (Every recipient gets their job description). Can I insert the fields, in a way that I can update my excel sheet, and my word file updates as well?

Thanks

Comment: Am I correct in understanding you want to build multiple Word documents automatically based on an Excel sheet that update as the spreadsheet is altered?

Comment: Yeah! It would be very nice, if it would be possible..

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic updating - it cannot be done.

What you need to do is use mail merge and then redo the merge whenever you make an update to the spreadsheet:

[This guide](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/word-help/word-mail-merge-a-walk-through-the-process-HA001034920.aspx) will talk you through the process of setting up a mail merge